# Keep left 0 during calculations

Tags: java, android, math

I am doing arithmetic addition operation but i want to keep the leftmost 0 whole time during the operation even if it has no value at all.

**My work till now**

i have `long` variable `long a = 03338023709` ;

when i do `a + 1` ; it is `3338023710` .

**wanted result**

as the `0` has no value at all but i want to keep it like `03338023710` not `3338023710`.

*please suggest me how to achieve this .*

Comment: btw a number prefixed with a `0` will be interpreted as an octal integer by the compiler. `long a = 03338023709` will not compile.  Use `long a = 3338023709L`, then format the output as suggested by @Arpan.

Comment: who is that person that gives a -1 ? is my question looks odd to you ?

Comment: The tooltip text for the downvote button is *"This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful"*. So one of those, probably.  Effort such as a simple google search for ["keep the leftmost 0 java"](https://www.google.com/search?q=keep+the+leftmost+0+java) which yields half a dozen similar questions already and makes your question not  very useful. Unclear perhaps because you didn't provide enough context, or the provided context is not realistic. Do you really care how a number is stored, or only what its output looks like? Or all of the above.  Who knows :)

Comment: so please suggest an answer thats really works mate . and mark it as duplicate . not just give a -1.

Comment: Not sure who you're addressing with "mate" here. I suppose some people are reluctant to do a simple google search and spell out the answers for you, if you're not making that little effort for yourself. The purpose of the "duplicate" is to make the same answers show up with different searches. Since it already showed the answers when searching for your question, perhaps they thought it wouldn't be useful. It's up to them if they mark as duplicate or downvote anyway. I didn't downvote btw - what I did do was add some comments with additional explanation.  Hope they helped, good luck to you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's suppose you are printing out the result, otherwise keeping the leading zero would make no sense.

In that case, you could do this:

```
long a = 03338023709;
a = a + 1;
String string = valueOf(a);
string = "0" + string;
```

and then use the string to print it out or whatever you need it for.

Comment: i was thinking about this solution . is there any better one .

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with "better one". If you use this only to print it out, this is the fastest and most secure way. And I think long cannot store number 033..., it would format it into 33... right away.

Comment: Actually `long a = 03338023709` or `long a = 03338023709L` will result in a compile time error (integer number too large) because it'll interpret it as octal integer.  Code in the answer will not compile.

Comment: @Arjan well that is then another problem, OP asked how to make string keep leading zeroes. This error would be thrown with any solution given to the question.

Comment: i have a constraint that there may be 1 or 2 "0" on the left side . but i applied your answer and it worked for me. thanks for help.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use [Formatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html).

```
String.format("%011d", a+1);
03338023710
```

This will pad enough zeroes to the left to keep the total length to 11 characters (in this case add 1 zero).

Otherwise, for adding a single zero to the left for each number, you can put the length of the number plus 1 in place of the 11.

Comment: This is way better than adding a "0" to the number as you can fix the "length" or magnitude of the number this way, without reinventing the wheel

Answer (score -1):

I assume that you want to keep the leading zero because you want to convert your value to a `String` (otherwise it would have no significance).
An easy solution would be to first convert the value as normal (e.g. with `Integer.toString(a)`) and to then just add leading zeroes until your `String` is as long as you wanted. Assuming you have a variable called `stringLength` containing your wished length you can use the code:

```
String s = Integer.toString(a);
while(s.length() < stringLength){
    s = "0" + s;
}
```